# what is max size of objectid(_id) fields in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, limit, objectid

In mongodb, what is max size of objectid(_id) field?
I can find auto-generated _id is 12 bytes,
but I wanna know how long _id field value can be if it is generated manually from client.

Is it also 1024 bytes?
([mongoDB Index Limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653676/mongodb-index-limits))
and automatically indexed? 
(in case I use _id for a shared key as default)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit on the length of \_id in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224128/is-there-a-limit-on-the-length-of-id-in-mongodb)

Comment: so, there is no specific limit for objectid but same as an index, which is limited to 1024 bytes. right?